# AngularJS Child directive is not getting called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, nested

I have a nested parent - child directives, the purpose if to draw a table..
The child directive is not getting called when called from within the parent (tag).
It works fine when tested independently.. I seems to have followed all the rules/syntax, require is in place..  I don't see the console logs statements I have in the child directive,  also there are no errors in the log.

Directives -

```
    var app = angular.module ('gridapp', []);

    app.directive ('gridControl', function(tableDataFactory){

        return {

            restrict: 'E',
            scope : {},
            controller : function($scope){

                $scope.columns = [];
                $scope.column = [];

                $scope.addColumnProperties = function(columnProperties) {
                    console.log("In addColumnProperties "+ columnProperties);
                    $scope.column = columnProperties;                   
                    $scope.columns.push($scope.column);

                    $scope.column = [];
                }
            },

            link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

                 console.log(attrs.source);

                 tableDataFactory
                    .get(
                            'http://localhost:8000/AngularTableWidget/json/accounts.json')
                    .then(
                            function(data) {
                                scope.items = data.items;
                                console.log("In grid directive" + scope.items);
                            });
            },

            templateUrl : '../template/gridtemplate.html'
        };
    });

    //child directive...
    app.directive('tableColumn', function(){

        return{
            restrict : 'E',
            scope : {}, 
            require : '^gridControl',

            link : function(scope, element, attrs, gridCtrl) {
                console.log("In tablecolumn "+ attrs.source);
                var colProp = [];
                console.log("In tablecolumn "+ attrs.caption);
                colProp.push(attrs.caption);
                colProp.push(attrs.source);

                gridCtrl.addColumnProperties(colProp);
            }
        };
    });
```

HTML -

```
<div>

<grid-control source="gridtable.json">  

 <table-column caption="Name" source="name"> </table-column>
 <table-column caption="Account" source="account"> </table-column>

 </grid-control>
```

template -

```
<div>

 <table>
 <tbody ng-repeat="row in items track by $index">
  <tr ng-repeat ="col in columns">
    <td>
    Test
    </td>
  </tr>  
  </tbody>
 </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Things *seem* OK; are you sure this is not a usage issue, i.e. are you sure you are not using it in a "strange" way? Can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: Where do you think  I could be wrong ?. accessing it like I access my other angular examples.. I will try to check it in fiddle.

Comment: I do not know, really, that is why I'd suggest you reproduced it in a fiddle.

Comment: Here is the fiddle link -- http://jsfiddle.net/n3QLf/1/

Comment: Copying stuff into the fiddle is not helping. Try reproducing the error in an otherwise working fiddle. Start by not using the self-closing form: `<table-column />`, rather the full end tag: `<table-column></table-column>`; I have seen Angular having trouble with the former.

Comment: No luck with that..I tried using both the directives individually, it worked, but not as nested..

Comment: It is related to using the templateURL in the parent directive, if I remove the templateUrl, it works fine... ie all the parent and child directives are called, else it just stops at parent link function.

Comment: 1. On grid-control diretive, add transclude = true.

Answer (score 1):

On grid-control directive, add transclude = true. Inside the grid-control template, add ng-transclude where ever the child directive going to be inserted. Without using transclude, the system will ignore the child directive.

I hope this helps.

Austin